# How to get indices from numpy index result containing multiple elements?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
a=np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1)
```

I want to use three numbers, where they sum up to 1. However, I noticed that `a[0]` will be:

```py
array([0.24414272, 0.01769199, 0.7381653 ])
```

an index that already contains three elements.

Is there any way to split them into three indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior if you *don't* pass `size` is to return a single dimensional array with the specified elements, per the docstring on the function:

> size : int or tuple of ints, optional
>
> Output shape. If the give shape is, e.g., `(m, n)`, then `m * n * k` [where `k` is size of input and sample sequences] samples are drawn. Default is `None`, in which case a vector of length `k` is returned.

By passing `size=1`, you explicitly tell it to make a multidimensional array of `size` samples (so, `1` sample, making the outer dimension 1), where not passing `size` (or passing `size=None`) would still make just one set of samples, as a single 1D array.

Short version: If you just drop the `,size=1` from your call, you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only thing you want, then this should work:

```
a=np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time use stackoverflow because of homework, 

you helped me a lot